# get record list from database with jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I prepared a page with bootstrap. There is an area in which I am getting records(title) into this area from databse(mysql) (I am getting this values with php on page.. not Jquery and ajax) on page. I want to that when I selected one of the these records, The Sub Records which are related with title must come automatically into own tables on page.. I use jquery and ajax. However, I couldn't process this.

My script :

```
$.getRecord = function () {
    $("#siteerror-panel").fadeIn(500);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "./ajax_read.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (response) {
            $("#hcList").html(response);
            //alert(response);
        }

    });

};
```

My `ajax_read.php` :

```
<?php
    require("data/baglan.php");
    $idWr = $_POST['idWr'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hcfailing where idWr = '56'  order by idHC ASC");
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
        echo '<tr>' + '<td>' + $data[0] + '</td>' + '<td class="hcexitcode">' + $data[2] + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs hcremoveExitCode"> Remove </a>' + '</td>' + '</tr>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: First, check your ajax respone if it is true, and then did you successfully trigger ajax function when you click element that you specified?

Answer (score 0):

Should be, concatenation operator ('.') need to be used

```
 echo '<tr><td>' . $data[0] . '</td><td class="hcexitcode">'. $data[2] . '</td><td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs hcremoveExitCode"> Remove </a></td></tr>';
```

instead of (because below one gives the output as `0`)

```
 echo '<tr>'+ '<td>' + $data[0] + '</td>' + '<td class="hcexitcode">' + $data[2] + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs hcremoveExitCode"> Remove </a>' + '</td>' + '</tr>';
```